# Calling Owin service running on localhost over https

Tags: jquery, ssl-certificate, owin, self-hosting

I have a web service based on Microsoft.Owin.Hosting running locally on port 8443 over https.  I have bound a certificate to it and am able to connect using Chrome using the web server address https://localhost:8443/queryendpoint.  I would like to call the web service however with a script running in a client browser page on that machine.

```
$.ajax({
        headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json",
            "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        type: "GET",
        "rejectUnauthorized": false, 
        url:"https://localhost:8433/queryendpoint",
        success:function(response){
          var r=JSON.parse(response);
.
.
.
        }
      });
```

When the script runs it causes an error:
`GET https://localhost:8433/queryendpoint net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

The error also comes back calling the web server address from Postman.

What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by specifying the correct port.  :/